# 畳み込みニューラルネットワークの入力画像の解像度について

Tags: 機械学習

畳み込みニューラルネットワーク(CNN)の入力画像について質問です。既存のモデルを使う場合入力画像のサイズが決まっていますが、ほとんどの画像の場合、サイズはバラバラだと思います。
そこで質問なのですが、CNNの入力用に大きな画像の解像度を落として小さな画像を生成するとCNNの精度はどのように変わるのでしょうか。

例えば、180x50の画像を32x32にスケールダウンすると精度が落ちたりするのでしょうか。
またその逆に小さい画像を大きくした場合に精度はどうなりますか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ケースバイケースかと思われますが、もともと畳み込み/プーリング自体がある意味「ぼやけさせる」行為になりますので各ラベル一律、一様にスケーリングを行った場合には影響はないかと思います。

ただしあるラベル画像はスケールアップ、あるラベルの画像はスケールダウン等になってしまうと
画像加工自体がラべリングに影響してしまうので誤判定が多くなってしまうと思います。
(スケーリング結果自体が学習結果に反映されてしまう。)